# How to identify additional code inclded by the compiler

Tags: c++, visual-studio, assembly, x86

I am learning assembly code patterns emitted by MS Visual Studio. The whole point of this experiment is to identify the `additional code` (i.e, assembly instructions) included by the compiler for each of the compiler options provided here: [MS Visual Studio Compiler Options](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/19z1t1wy.aspx).

I have planned to write a small C++ program and try this each option. But, before doing that I want to know is there any better way to get this information or already available somewhere.

**Example:**
Instructions `mov %gs:0x14,%eax` in the function prologue and `xor %gs:0x14,%eax` in the function epilogue checks for buffer overflow, inserted by this compiler option `/GS`. Similarly, I want to know the additional instructions included (if any) for all other compiler options.

Comment: Compiler options don't just add instructions, depending on the option and the code you're compiling, they can replace instructions and remove instructions as well.

Comment: Beware the evil optimizers!

Comment: Yes, I am aware of this situation. But, I have done something similar for `gcc`, where with `-g` option, I managed to roughly identify the assembly instructions emitted by each line of code and the additional ones corresponds to  the code inserted by the compiler. This is not a precise approach but worked for me.

Comment: My program is a very simple one (just 10 lines of code), so its relatively easy to understand the assembly code.

Comment: You could save the assembly output of each version and use `diff` to compare

Comment: The `-g` option doesn't normally add any actual assembly instructions, just assembly directives that cause debug information to be emitted in the object file. Also, you should be aware of the fact that the Visual C++ compiler doesn't generate assembly and then assemble that into an object file the way GCC does. Instead it generates an object file directly. If you tell it to produce assembly output it does this in addition to producing the object file, and the assembly doesn't contain everything in the object file. The assembly output generated by Visual C++ usually can't be assembled.